# ASDoc Base Class was not Found

Tags: actionscript-3, asdoc

I've been trying to generate documentation for some action script 3 files using ASDocs and I've been getting the error:

```
Error: The difinition of base class TextInput was not found
```

The class is from fl.controls library.  I used Flash Profesional CS5 to write the classes, and the command line to run ASDoc.

I've been looking up how others deal with it and they are using either FlashDeveloper or Flex Builder it seems, neither of which I have.  So usually they say add in -libarary-path that would include Flex Builder, but it seems that has been discontinued.  I also tried using the path:

```
/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4/sdks/4.0.0/frameworks/libs/
```

without success.

What is the path that would include the fl library?

Comment: can you show your config file and/or commandline instruction?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you need to add these libraries to your configuration.

On Mac+FlashCS6.0, the library containing `TextInput` should be here:

`/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CS6/Common/Configuration/Components/User\ Interface/TextInput.swc`

Comment: The path seems right, but when I use it I get this error: Error: unable to load SWC Accordion.swc: unknown element componentPackage found in swc section in catalog.xml.